# Text from EditText not saving in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I have an EditText and I want to save the text in the EditText as a string in Shared Preferences if the string is not empty or null. However my app is crashing with the following code:

Activity.java:

```
Button buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    assert buttonNext != null;
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (checkForGuardianNames()) {
                Log.i("Guardian names: ", "check passed");
                Log.i("ActivityEditText", inputGuardian1.getText().toString());
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, inputGuardian1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                saveGuardianNames();

                } else {
                    promptToFillField("Guardian");
                    Log.i("Guardian names: ", "check failed");
//                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UserInfoActivity.this, "Works well part 2 "+ inputGuardian1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//                    toast.show();
                }
            }
```

Now I know that the `checkForGuardianNames()` passes but the app crashes on calling `saveGuardianNames()` method.

My `saveGuardianNames()` :

```
private void saveGuardianNames(){
    String guardian1 = inputGuardian1.getText().toString();
    String guardian2 = inputGuardian2.getText().toString();
    String guardian3 = inputGuardian3.getText().toString();
    String guardian4 = inputGuardian4.getText().toString();
    Log.i("Value: ", "Dummy");
    Log.i("saveGuardianNames", "Called");


        if (!inputGuardian1.getText().toString().matches("")){
            Log.i("Putting text", "in sp");
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Guardian 1", guardian1).apply();
            Log.i("Putting text", "passed");
        }
}
```

Now I see `saveGuardianNames: check passed` in the logcat so the method is called properly but the line just above that isn't (`Log.i("Value: ", "Dummy");`) and there isn't any mention of it in the LogCat. Also, from what I understand, the if statement is never called or crashes before `Log.i("Putting text", "in sp");` is executed.

My error LogCat:

```
08-24 01:40:43.712 1497-1497/com.bluefirelabs.apptiva I/Guardian names:: check passed
08-24 01:40:43.732 1497-1497/com.bluefirelabs.apptiva I/saveGuardianNames: Called
08-24 01:40:43.732 1497-1497/com.bluefirelabs.apptiva E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.bluefirelabs.apptiva, PID: 1497
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences.edit()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.bluefirelabs.apptiva.UserInfoActivity$override.saveGuardianNames(UserInfoActivity.java:374)
                                                                            at com.bluefirelabs.apptiva.UserInfoActivity$override.static$access$200(UserInfoActivity.java:27)
                                                                            at com.bluefirelabs.apptiva.UserInfoActivity$override.access$dispatch(UserInfoActivity.java)
                                                                            at com.bluefirelabs.apptiva.UserInfoActivity.access$200(UserInfoActivity.java:0)
                                                                            at com.bluefirelabs.apptiva.UserInfoActivity$1$override.onClick(UserInfoActivity.java:112)
                                                                            at com.bluefirelabs.apptiva.UserInfoActivity$1$override.access$dispatch(UserInfoActivity.java)
                                                                            at com.bluefirelabs.apptiva.UserInfoActivity$1.onClick(UserInfoActivity.java:0)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
                                                                            at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10885)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22533)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I am bit perplexed as to why some lines are being executed while one before it isn't and why the app is crashing before saving anything to Shared Preferences. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As in log `sharedPreferences` is null

Comment: where did u create and initialize `sharedPreferences`, can you show that

Comment: Initialize sharedPreferences before use it

Comment: I initialized sharedPreferences in onCreate: `final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.bluefirelabs.apptiva", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!inputGuardian1.getText().toString().matches("")){
            Log.i("Putting text", "in sp");
          if(sharedPreferences != null){
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Guardian 1", guardian1).apply();
            Log.i("Putting text", "passed");
           }else{
            sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Guardian 1", guardian1).apply();
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After all the editings, you need to call this,
editor.commit();

please go to this website http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to do sharedPreferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
                getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
```

and then `editor.putString(`...

and then `editor.apply()`

Answer (score 0):

Your `SharedPreferences` object is not initialised, so please initialise it   like

if you are doing in activity then do like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("YouKeyName", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

editor.putString("Guardian 1", "Hi");
editor.commit();
```

if you are doing in Fragment then do like this

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

 editor.putString("Guardian 1", "Hi");
 editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);        
sharedpreferences.edit().putString("key", "value").commit();
```